# How do I pass a variable from my DIV tag through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, get, favorites

I am new-ish to jQuery and AJAX, and I'm trying to make a Favorites link which calls a script (containing database queries) when clicked using AJAX. I have a function which calls a script when an HTML tag is clicked. It works! However, I need to pass some variables to that script in order to make it work, and I'm stuck. How can I do this through jQuery?

This is my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".favorites").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "scripts/ajax_favorites.php", success: function(result){
          $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
      });
    });
```

This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="div1" class="favorites">[Favorite]</div>
```

I've tried adding other elements, including a "?e=(event.target.name)" after my URL, and it seems to not work. I think my syntax is way off. I added "name" and included my ID, but couldn't successfully call it in the jQuery.

What I'm hoping to do is add something to the DIV tag which can indicate an ID so that when clicked, it runs my script and passes that variable.

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` show, if its shows nothing than check your `ajax_favorites.php`, you can add relative snippet code from your php file to here could be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select any attribute from the element has been clicked for example if you want to garb the id you can do it like this

```
$(".favorites").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/ajax_favorites.php?e="+id, success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can use data attribute in your html get a value from there

```
$(".favorites").click(function () {
    var fav = $(this).data('fav');
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/ajax_favorites.php?e=" + fav, success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

html will be

```
<div id="div1" class="favorites" data-fav="fav1">[Favorite]</div>
```